# PHP copy function not working inside foreach loop

Tags: php, xml, copy

I am trying to copy a remote picture into a local folder using xml file. XML file is below;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<items> 
   <item>
     <image>
       http://www.example.com/image.jpg,
       https://www.example.com/image2.jpg
     </image> 
    </item> 
 </items>
```

After uploading the file using html form. I am inserting the images into an array and after that using that array in foreach loop to copy from remote url into local folder using php copy function. The code is below:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']) or die("Error: Cannot create object");
foreach ($xml->children() as $row) {
  $images = explode(',', $row->images);

  foreach ($images as  $image) { 
   copy($image, 'images/properties/'.$property_id.'/'.uniqid().'.jpg');
  }
}
```

Using the above code does not work but if i hardcode the image inside copy function, the images is copied. see code below;

```
<?php 
  $images = explode(',', $row->images);
  foreach ($images as  $image) { 
    copy('https://www.example.com/image2.jpg', 'images/properties/'.$property_id.'/'.uniqid().'.jpg');
  }
?>
```

so the propblem is copy function is not working with variable. I tried to wrap the variable in a single and double quote too but still didnt work.

Can any one tell me why?

Comment: Post the code that parses the XML document and initializes `$images`. The items extracted from a [`SimpleXMLElement`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php) are not what they seem to be.

Comment: updated the post

Comment: There is no `images` in `$row`.

Comment: image urls are displayed if i echo the $images after using explode.

Comment: @axiac You've right ! You could make an anwser, I'll delete mine if you want. Dalyan, you have prepend name of users with `@`, if not, they not get your comment.

Comment: `$images = explode(',', $row->images);` -- there is no `images` in `$row`. There is `image` but that's something else. The URLs are not separated by `,` in the example XML you posted; `explode()` returns one big string that contains more than one URL. Of course nothing works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some spaces/newline in your image names, after "exploding" your string. The `copy()` function doesn't work with extra spaces **before** URLs. You could use `trim()` to remove them.

```
foreach ($images as  $image) { 
    copy(trim($image), 'images/properties/'.$property_id.'/'.uniqid().'.jpg');
}
```

Then, you have to get your data from the XML like this :

```
foreach ($xml->item->image as $row) {
    $images = explode(',', (string)$row);
    $images = array_map('trim', $images); // trim your names (so the code above is no longer required.
}
```